# How to implement async in spring boot for getting response over asynchronous call?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, asynchronous

How can i call 3 different GET rest apis asynchronously in Spring Boot? Currently its taking alot of time to execute this apis sequentially. Let me know how to do this asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use async-http-client as given in the following url : https://www.baeldung.com/async-http-client

2.You can use AsyncRestTemplate. In AsyncRestTemplate object you need to send the following three parameters.
* endpoint uri,
* request entity with headers, 
*and response object.

Catch all those in to a ListenableFuture object where implement the override methods of callback in the case of failure and success.

For both of these approach, you have to create request objects and call the services. And the call backmethod will capture the result in the response objects. You can merge responses together and then do your business.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @EnableAsync annotation at the configuration level to enable async processing and @Async at the method level which needs to be invoked asynchronously.

For further details please refer to the below link

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async